# DataServiceConfiguration is internal so I can't enable WCF data paging?

Tags: wcf-data-services, data-paging

I have a problem with my WCF Data Service, and this one is just plain weird.  I'm trying to enable paging so that large collections will be handled better, which was the whole idea behind me using data services in the first place.

However, all the examples I've seen are based on using `DataServiceConfiguration`, as shown here: http://blogs.msdn.com/astoriateam/archive/2010/02/02/server-paging-in-data-services.aspx, and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration.aspx.

Now comes the weird bit - this class isn't there when I try to access it (my service was set up using `IDataServiceConfiguration`, the interface, and the class itself doesn't appear in the intellisense, nor does it go green or have the red "resolve" smart tag), and I have System.Data.Services referenced.

Now, if I try building, it tells me that it's down to the protection levels, so I went hunting.  Using Reflector I found the class, marked internal...  So what's happening here?  I'm using VS 2008 SP1 and my project is building against .NET 3.5 SP1.

The reason this is important is because the properties that control page size are defined on the class not the interface

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I must be blind.

I'd read that there was an update that gave this, but I'd assumed it was in the current download package, or would have been shipped by automatic update.  Not so - I needed to download this package:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4b710b89-8576-46cf-a4bf-331a9306d555#filelist

Once I've installed that, the class magically appears.

Hope that helps somebody.

Thanks